# Schematic for 3 input power selection with reverse polarity protection

Tags: power-electronics

I'm trying to design a circuit that will allow 3 separate inputs (USB 5V, PoE 5V and VIN 7-28 V all DC) and pick one of them (based on priority). It must allow reverse polarity protection on the VIN input (the others are from USB and Power-over-Ethernet so they won't need reverse protection). I also need it to provide as close to 5V as possible on the output (so simple diodes won't work) and the circuit can't backfeed 5V into the VIN or PoE outputs (the PoE module will put a large load on the output if presented with 5V on the output pins, tried that).

Inputs:

- 7-28V DC via connector. Needs reverse polarity protection up to 28V (to protect from user mistakes).
- PoE module, can't have 5V on its output pins when not used (when no PoE switch is used)
- USB connector

**Features:**

- Only one of the power inputs should be used at any point (based on priority)
- 3A max current
- 5V output

**Question:**
Can you point me in the right direction of what type of circuit will allow this type of functionality?
I'm not looking for a complete solution, I just listed the features/inputs here to set the context.

Comment: You need to ask a question and not leave it to the reader as to what you really need. My guess: look-up "power-path controller"

Comment: Good comment, thanks, I've edited to actually ask a question as well. I'll look up power-path controller, thanks!